# How to add multiple locations in single EditText in android

Tags: android

How to add multiple locations in single EditText in android.We want to create **Tags** of locations.

Comment: Just comma separate them... What is your question?

Comment: Something like this? https://github.com/splitwise/TokenAutoComplete

Comment: There are couple of libraries which will help you do it. Your best bet is to check Android Arsenal. See this link - http://android-arsenal.com/search?q=chips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to written code to add multiple location in single EditText in android.

```
 void updateAddressLayout() {

    final ViewGroup locationGroup = (ViewGroup) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.locationsLayout);
    for (int i = locationGroup.getChildCount() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        locationGroup.removeViewAt(i);
    }
    final LayoutInflater inflater =getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    for (int i=0; i < mylocations.size(); i++){
        final View locationView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.include_location_tag_chip, locationGroup, false);
        final TextView locationText = (TextView)locationView.findViewById(R.id.info_text);
        final ImageView delImage = (ImageView)locationView.findViewById(R.id.icon_del);
        final String primaryAddress = mylocations.get(i).getAddressLine(0) + " " + mylocations.get(i).getAddressLine(1) + " " + mylocations.get(i).getLocality() + " " + mylocations.get(i).getPostalCode();
        locationText.setText(primaryAddress);
        final int finalI = i;
        delImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                        .setTitle("Alert!")
                        .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete location ")
                        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                               mylocations.remove(finalI);
                                locationGroup.removeViewAt(finalI);
                            }
                        }).setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }).show();
            }
        });
        locationGroup.addView(locationView);
    }
}
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_GET_LOCATION) {
            mCurrentAddress = data.getParcelableExtra("LOC_ADDRESS");
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"You can add only three locations", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if (mCurrentAddress.getAddressLine(0) != null || mCurrentAddress.getAddressLine(1) != null || mCurrentAddress.getLocality() != null || mCurrentAddress.getPostalCode() != null) {
                    if (mylocations.size() <3) {
                    mylocations.put(mylocations.size(), (Address) data.getParcelableExtra("LOC_ADDRESS"));
                }
                updateAddressLayout();
            }
            return;
        }
    }
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED && requestCode == REQUEST_GET_LOCATION) {
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```